# R S3 cat() output from function

Tags: r

I've got a problem with output from S3 function. I try to overload "+" function to act with two vectors like with polynomial parameters. It's my university project. Code is below:

```
'+.ply' <- function(a,b){
  size <- max(length(a$polynomial),length(b$polynomial)) 
  size
  aAdd <- a$polynomial
  bAdd <- b$polynomial

  if (length(aAdd) == size) {
   aAdd = aAdd
  } else {
    length(aAdd) <- size   
  }
  aAdd[is.na(aAdd)] <- 0

  if (length(bAdd) == size) {
    bAdd = bAdd
  } else {
    length(bAdd) <- size    
  }
  bAdd[is.na(bAdd)] <- 0

 cat("Polynomial of degree ", paste(length(aAdd+bAdd)-1), 
                  " with coefficients ", paste(aAdd+bAdd))
}
```

Code is working fine, but in return it gives me output

```
*Polynomial of degree  3  with coefficients  3 4 6 3NULL*
```

I need to use cat in order to avoid [1] index which occurs while I'm using print, paste combo. I know that there are plenty threads about this problem, but I can't find any sollution for such problem during function overloading. I will be thankful for help.

Comment: You must give a working example for us to know what to do. Can you post the function call code, and the output of `dput(a)` and `dput(b)` **in the question**, please?

Comment: Simplify: `if (length(aAdd) != size) length(aAdd) <- size` is enough.

Comment: Your `+` method must return a value. If you want to print in a specific way, your return object should also have a class and you should define `print` and `format` methods for it. In your `print` method you can use `cat` if you are really opposed to the standard way R prints everything (because almost everything in R is a vector in the broader sense).

Comment: Thank you Roland for a tip!!! It gave me sollution for my problem :). Now everything works as I expected.